# How to call DataAnnotation validation on blur in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, data-annotations, unobtrusive-validation

In my project i have requirement that if a field is mandatory and you erase the existing data, an error message is immediately displayed (in red) asking the field should not be blank. However, I have not yet started entering the data. The error message should NOT be displayed till you loss the focus i.e error message display on blur.For validation i am using data annotation.So how can i achieved it using data annotation.Please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $.validator.setDefaults({
    onkeyup: false
  })
</script>
```